# How to filter Follow-Up Emails in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I create a filter for someone's email and it automatically goes to a folder.
For all of his following emails, they go into that folder. But for anyone who REPLIES to His email it goes directly in my inbox.
Is there a setting in Gmail that will filter these replies (follow-up) emails into the same folder as the sender's?

Comment: Note that Gmail uses labels, not folders.

Comment: Yes... well how do I forward replies to my filtered emails into those same Labels?

Comment: Try adjusting the filter to look for the triggering email address in the From: To: and CC: fields. That can tag the emails you send in reply as well, keeping the whole of the conversation in the same folder.

Comment: are you using conversations, or have you disabled conversation view?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a filter like this:

```
from:jdoe@gmail.com
apply label: jdoe_messages
```

The simplest way to have messages from John Doe, as well as message sent *to* him, is:

```
has the words: (from:jdoe@gmail.com OR to:jdoe@gmail.com)
apply label jdoe_messages
```

That way, any message from John Doe, or with John Doe's email address in the `to:` field, will be seen by the same filter.

Comment: This works great except for emails that are sent to certain mailing lists, which will keep the `to` field as *just* the mailing list address for any replies. For those, you can add the following to the "Has the words" field: "jdoe@gmail.com wrote" OR "John Doe wrote" (including the quotes and the OR). Email clients differ in how they do replies, hence the OR.